# Reduce the mixing time by switching a regular state to an absorbing state in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume we have a homogeneous Markov chain with $3$ states $s_1,s_2,s_3$ and the transition probability matrix is

$P = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right].$

The steady-state probability is therefore
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0.2857 & 0.2857 & 0.4286\end{array}\right].$

Next, I need to switch one of the regular states, say $s_3$, to an absorbing state, and thus the transition probability matrix becomes

$Q = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$

The steady-state probability now is 
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  & 1\end{array}\right].$

The question: is it possible to show, in general, that the mixing time can be reduced by switching one of the regular states to the absorbing state in a homogeneous Markov chain?

Comment: If the underlying graph has two components definetly not.

Comment: This method is sometimes used to find the mean time to reach one specified state, given the starting state.